# When I open terminal i find this message . how i resolve this?

Tags: python3, opencv, anaconda, pandas

I see [This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1mev.png) when i open terminal. It occur after my failure in installing open cv and pandas on my computer.

In this image the error is

```
/home/ujjwal/anaconda3/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for      VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/home/ujjwal/anaconda3/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
```

How i Solve this?

Comment: can you please copy and paste it into your question?

Comment: Posting images of text is discouraged. Properly formatted (with the `{}` button) copy-and-paste of the command and error message is what we need.

Comment: /home/ujjwal/anaconda3/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/home/ujjwal/anaconda3/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.

Comment: @UjjwalKar please [edit] your question and include that information, instead of posting it in a difficult to read comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to do a clean uninstall of anaconda and reinstall.

But if that's not possible

you need to install the `virtualenvwrapper` package, but specifically with the `pip` associated with the `base` anaconda python

`~/anaconda3/bin/pip install virtualenvwrapper`

If that installation fails, then there's something really broken with your anaconda installation, you need to wipe it and start over

Comment: Thank you it work

Comment: No problem, if this solved your problem please remember to upvote and accept the answer

Comment: I cannot upvote. As I am new in here I have less then 15 reputation

Comment: You should be able to upvote on your own questions

Comment: *answers to your own questions; but that's irregardless, checking the checkmark under the vote buttons is more important as it finished the question

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/F2iDTuGSGeHzA7c48

Comment: See this image . I can't

Comment: That's fine, but you need to click the little check mark under the voting arrows

Comment: Okkkkkkkkkkkkkkk